# How to set app level cache directory for OkHttp Client

Tags: android, caching, retrofit, okhttp

I am using Retrofit - **OkHttp** for web service call.
While using `OkHttpClient.Builder` of OkHttp to get `OkHttpClient`,
there is parameter for **cache**.

See below line:

```
OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .cache(?);// This last parameter
```

How to set this cache parameter ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using below code we can able to set Application level cache directory for **OkHttpClient**:

```
// Install an HTTP cache in the application cache directory.

    File cacheDir = new File(app.getCacheDir(), "http");
    // [app] is your Application class object.
    // using [app.getCacheDir()], get app cache directory.

    Cache cache = new Cache(cacheDir, DISK_CACHE_SIZE);
    //DISK_CACHE_SIZE is constant for OkHttpClient cache directory size.    
   //private int DISK_CACHE_SIZE = 50 * 1024 * 1024; // 50MB


    OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .cache(cache);

    OkHttpClient okHttpClient=builder.build();
```